# How to only allow display capture with navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia

Tags: javascript

I want to allow a user to capture their screen, however, I don't want them to have the option to capture a window, app, or tab, only the whole screen. How would I do this, if I can, using `navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia()`

Or I want to know what the user decided to share, ex. if the user shared a tab, window, or whole screen.

Answer (score 0):

Use `stream.getVideoTracks()[0].getSettings().displaySurface` to get the type of sharing.